# Facebook Analytics Conversion API events pushed from server

Tags: facebook, facebook-analytics

Recently I've started working with Facebook Conversion API to send events from serverside.
I'm using the test-event feature of the Facebook event-manager and when I set the email of the userData to a dummy value, it doesn't show up on the dashboard.

I've also tried removing the email and adding only the country ('US') and it doesn't show up either on the dashboard of the event-manager, test-event.

The data is like this:

```
{ "data": [ { "event_name": "subscriptionCreated", "event_time": 1612508965, "user_data": { "em": "f660ab912ec121d1b1e928a0bb4bc61b15f5ad44d5efdc4e1c92a25e99b8e44a" } } ], "partner_agent": null, "test_event_code": null, "namespace_id": null, "upload_id": null, "upload_tag": null, "upload_source": null, "access_token": "access-token", "id": "1361131684239273" }
```

Nevertheless, I'm not getting any error in the response either. It's a HTTP 200 with the following response.

> {"events_received":1,"messages":[],"fbtrace_id":"AAAztL5vcQGb7v9bYZJ9QoP"}

Could anyone provide any clue into why these events aren't showing up in the dashboard ?

Comment: Did you find what was the problem? I am having similar issue.